# carrierwave works with form but not API in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave, strong-parameters, rails-api

I am using carrierwave to accept an image from a Python API.  I have the following code:

```
  def create
    @person = Person.new(person_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @person.save
        format.html { redirect_to @person, notice: 'Person was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @person }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

def person_params
  params.permit(:client_file_name, :name, :picture)
end
```

I had to take out `params.require(:person)` because the Python library I am using called `requests` does not allow you to send files in that form.

According to the server logs, the image is saving:

```
Started POST "/people" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-19 11:49:19 -0500
Processing by PeopleController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"picture"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fe5e8e900b8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/77/2f_jjrld0dxgq3t8xv6clvph0000gn/T/RackMultipart20171119-13141-1nunpha.png>, @original_filename="Phil.png", @content_type=nil, @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture\"; filename=\"Phil.png\"\r\n">}
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "people" ("picture", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["picture", "Phil.png"], ["created_at", "2017-11-19 16:49:19.776189"], ["updated_at", "2017-11-19 16:49:19.776189"]]
   (0.6ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/people/8
Completed 302 Found in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)
```

I am only doing this locally.  When I look in the directory where the image should be saved, there is an image there called `Phil.png` which is what should happen except the image has zero bytes.

When I upload the same image using a form, everything works as expected.  How do I fix this?

Comment: I am not sure if it is relevant. The enctype is `multipart/form-data`? I once had a similar issue, but don't recall if there was an image with 0bytes though.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.  Rails requires you to set the content-type to `image/png`, so adding that to the request solved the problem.